# I am getting 120 volts when checking the hot and neutral on the outlet but when I check the hot and ground I’m only getting 80 volts?

Tags: voltage

I am getting 120 volts when checking the hot and neutral but only 80 volts when checking the hot to ground?

Comment: Volt measurement between neutral and ground?  Maybe a loose/dirty ground connection.

Comment: Yes, check and see if you get ~40V from ground to neutral.

Comment: Plug a long extension cord into a distant ground and check the voltage between the ground in the extension cord and the ground in the receptacle of concern. There should be 0.0 V both AC and DC. If there is zero or close, then it will not harm your meter to change to an Ohm scale and measure the resistance. It should be close to zero. If it is not, then suspect a poor ground connection.

Answer (score 2):

1. Plug a 3-prong circuit tester into the receptcle. Does it indicate a missing ground or other fault? Check other receptacles too.
2. Plug a long extension cord into a distant grounded receptacle (preferably one that tested OK with a 3-prong tester) and check the voltage between the ground in the extension cord and the ground in the receptacle of concern.

If there is a significant voltage between these two grounds, you have a problem. DO NOT CHANGE THE METER TO RESISTANCE (OHMS) MODE. This could damage your meter.

There should be 0.0 V both AC and DC. If there is zero or close, then it will not harm your meter to change to an Ohm scale and measure the resistance. It should be close to zero. If it is not, then suspect a poor ground connection.